# Popup blocker markup bug on IE6

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-6

In asp.net mvc 3 i have a page,where there are two forms. They contain labels, textboxes and dropdowns. On IE6 on sumbiting form ( on success submit new window have to be opened, submit is ajax post action ) appears popup-blocker notification. When notification appears( or sometimes after closing notification at the top of window, it thing it's because of cache, maybe ) all content in forms except dropdownlists(!?) dissapears. It partly appears after focusing on dropdowns and then clicking on place where other content have to be placed.

I'm using jquery 1.5.2, jquery validate plugin and jquery.ajax.

Submit button:

```
<div class="button">
    <input type="submit" value="Sumbit" />
</div>
```

Callback:

```
    onSuccess: function (response) {
        var jsonResult = eval("(" + response.responseText + ")");
        hideStatusMessage();
        if (jsonResult.Success) {
            //StatusMessage is span that displays result of submit
            showStatusMessage(jsonResult.Message);
            redirectTo(jsonResult.RedirectTo);
        } else {
            // We got some error
            showStatusMessage(jsonResult.Message);
        }
    }
```

Redirection:

```
var redirectTo = function (urlString) {
    var params =
        "width=" + screen.width + ", height=" + screen.height +
        ", top=0, left=0, fullscreen=yes, location=no";
    var newWin = window.open(urlString, '_blank', params, false);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the html of the submit button (or <a> element if that's what you are using) and the javascript function that posts and handles the callback?

Comment: jrummell: that's nice, but ie6 support on my project doesn't depend on my opinion :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I can't see the whole code, I'm going to go on a hunch.  I think that the page is trying to POST to its current location.  This kind of refreshes the page but not completely.  This could be what you're experiencing with the content being erased from textboxes.

If this is the case, you will need to prevent the submit button from being able to post when this popup is expected.  You can do this by calling [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the event or by returning false from the function that executes on button click.  Prefer the stopPropagation method if you have access to the event.